# StackOverFlow , Twitter, ... IOS App... how they handle Scrolling in their Pages

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

**How They Handle ScrollView and SubTable?**

[image]
[image]

when parent scrollview is at top, scrolling up, move it to bottom and then child tableview scroll...

StackOverFlow IOS APP :

https://aorb.ir/content/sackoverflow.mp4

Twitter IOS APP :

https://aorb.ir/content/twitter.mp4

Comment: Did you manage to find out how this works? Any direction would be helpful.